# How to pass input id to jquery using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to set the value of input box. If I assign the input id with `$('#id').val(value)` its working properly but I assign the variable then it doesn't work. please help.. my Sample code is

```
var box = '<?php echo addslashes($box); ?>';
function rowSelect(){
$('#'+box).val(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: can u show the code that saves the selecteditem

Comment: What does the generated JavaScript code look like?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `$('#'+box).val(selectedItem);` line of code so the issue is either with the value of the variable `box` or the value of the variable `selectedItem`.  You will have to show us the code that populates those variables for us to be able to help.  Also, I'd suggest you look at the generated HTML (what the browser sees via View/Source in the browser) so you can remove any PHP echo issues from the equation and so we can see what the actual javascript is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it without single quotes because `php echo is considered it as string.

```
var box = <?php echo addslashes($box); ?>;    
function rowSelect(){
     $('#'+box).val(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: thanks sir.. the code is working for me... any other suggestion?